# Rank the Products table based on listprice for all rows that have a makeflag=1, grouping by daystomanufacture

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Rank the Products table based on listprice for all rows that have a makeflag=1, grouping by daystomanufacture. 
Using the information above, create a sql to see like listprices with same ranking but no gaps in numbers for the rank.

This is the code I have.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
SELECT Dense_Rank () OVER (PARTITION BY a.ProductID ORDER BY a.ListPrice) AS 'Ranking',
a.ProductID, b.Name, b.DaysToManufacture, a.ListPrice
FROM Production.ProductListPriceHistory a 
INNER JOIN Production.Product b
ON a.ProductID= b. ProductID
WHERE MakeFlag = 1
ORDER BY Ranking;
```

This works, however some of the listprices aren't grouped together. Should I have the ON statement be a.ListPrice = b.ListPrice?

Comment: Which part of your code should do the grouping?

Comment: Product has `ListPrice`, you don't need to join the history. The partition should be by DaysToManufacture